# comparing two arrays , If the date matches create a new array to be used

Tags: java, arrays, google-apps-script, compare

Hi I currently have two arrays full of data sets, I'm trying to compare both by the address column to see if an address matches and if so pass along the data set to a new array to be used somewhere else.

So far I have this and its currently not comparing just passing along the IHMS array.

```java
var rangeMaster = ssMaster.getRange('A2:G2000');
var rangeIhms = ssIhms.getRange('A2:K2000');
Master = rangeMaster.getValues();
IHMS = rangeIhms.getValues();

//Logger.log(Master);
var i = [6];
var j = [1];
for (var i in IHMS) {
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in Master) {
        if(IHMS[i].join() == Master[j].join()) {
            var matchedValFromArray2 = IHMS[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
 
//Logger.log(IHMS);
Logger.log(matchedValFromArray2);

finDes.getRange('A2:X1000').clearContent();
var h = IHMS.length;    // get number of rows
var l = IHMS[0].length; // get number of columns

finDes.getRange(finDes.getLastRow() + 1, 1, h, l).setValues(IHMS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PGSystemTester already provided a very good solution for sheets if that is an option for you, but if you really need script, then check this answer below:

```
function matchAddress() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssMaster = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var ssIhms = ss.getSheetByName("IHMS");
  var finDes = ss.getSheetByName("FinDes");

  // Considering sheets' adresses are stored in different columns
  // (1-indexing sheets vs 0-indexing arrays, so subtract 1)
  var masterAddressCol = 2; // Column C
  var ihmsAddressCol = 0;   // Column A

  // Range is filtered to exclude rows with no address column value 
  // (assumed empty rows)
  var Master = ssMaster.getRange('A2:G2000').getValues().filter(row => row[masterAddressCol]);
  var IHMS = ssIhms.getRange('A2:K2000').getValues().filter(row => row[ihmsAddressCol]);

  // Get addresses from master sheet
  var masterAddresses = Master.map(row => row[masterAddressCol]);

  // Filter IHMS by only including rows that have address in master
  var matchedValFromArray2 = IHMS.filter(row => masterAddresses.includes(row[ihmsAddressCol]));

  finDes.getRange('A2:X1000').clearContent();
  var h = matchedValFromArray2.length;    // get number of rows
  var l = matchedValFromArray2[0].length; // get number of columns

  finDes.getRange(finDes.getLastRow() + 1, 1, h, l).setValues(matchedValFromArray2);
}
```

#### Master:

[image: master]

#### IHMS:

[image: ihms]

#### FinDes (Output):

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I filtered the range to exclude blank rows (no 1st column value), feel free to remove it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which or how the arrays are supposed to be output, but I am pretty sure you can accomplish what you need without using google app scripts. Basically create a filtered array and use the `match` function to include values where the addresses match.

You can see a sample [in this file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APVRT8hRH_4QMjbYh63U-h7H8QhkS8nj5hSyVn7g6Sw/edit#gid=0)

I used this formula to create the output array:
`=Filter(A4:D,ISNUMBER(match(C4:C,H:H,0)))`

Here's some sample results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first we need to have look of how to use for loop.
for example you can consider.

```
var h={'hello','hi'};
for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++)
       h[i];
```

if i=0 h[i] is hello
i=1 h[i] is hi

```
  var h={'hello','hi'};
  for(var j in h)
```

for first iteration value of i is hello so h[hello] may be undefined.

and you have defined var i,j in both local for loop scope and class level scope so by default it will take local for loop variable.